# RegEx: Match second occurrence of character set in in quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking to match the second ocurrence of a character set enclosed in quotes.
For example:

`"{08165EA0-E946-11CF-9C87-00AA005127ED}"="WebCheckWebCrawler"`

I only want to select `WebCheckWebCrawler`, not `08165EA0-E946-11CF-9C87-00AA005127ED`.

Here's a what I have so far but I'm unable to select the second occurrence.

https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/4

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use [`="([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/6) and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working in PowerShell and when I run your RegEx I get two matches
    WebCheckWebCrawler and ="WebCheckWebCrawler".

This is my test code:

$str = '"{08165EA0-E946-11CF-9C87-00AA005127ED}"="WebCheckWebCrawler"';

$pattern = '="([^"]+)"'

$str -match $pattern

$Matches.Values

Comment: If you use `$str -match $pattern` then the value can be accessed via `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generic solution**

Getting nth occurrence of a match is in most cases achieved through *extracting all, multiple matches* from the string, and then getting the necessary item through its index. Just a quick sample in Powershell:

```
Select-String '"([^"]+)"' -input $str -AllMatches | % { $_.matches } |
    % { $_.groups[1].value } | select -Skip 1 -First 1
```

Here, `Select-String '"([^"]+)"' -input $str -AllMatches | % { $_.matches } | % { $_.groups[1].value }` gets all matches and collects all Group 1 values (substrings within double quotes excluding the quotes), and `select -Skip 1 -First 1` omits the first item and gets the next one that becomes first. In other languages, there are similar ways. **However**, this takes a bit of code and is considered "expensive" since memory should be allocated for all the matches and their internal structures.

**A specific solution**

In text editors, and in languages with no regex method that allows fetching multiple regex matches, the above solution does not work. In those cases, this kind of regex is used to get the second match:

```
^(?:.*?"([^"]*)"){2}
^(?:[^"]*"([^"]*)"){2}
^(?:.*?(<YOUR_PATTERN_HERE>)){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2KjJh/1/). **Note**: this requires a regex method that returns the whole match object structure with the captured substrings (submatches, captures). Also, note that the `.*?` does not match line break chars by default, and is slower than `[^"]*` that in its turn can match line break chars, and is faster.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group start:

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `"` - a `"` char
  - `([^"]*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more (`*`) chars other than `"`
  - `"` - a `"` char
- `){2}` - end of the group, repeat twice.

*What if you want the whole match?* This depends on the regex library. In Powershell, it is easy to get since .NET regex supports an infinite-width lookbehind patterns:

```
(?<=^(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"){1}[^"]*")[^"]*(?=")
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29%7B1%7D%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29%5B%5E%22%5D*%28%3F%3D%22%29&i=%22%7B08165EA0-E946-11CF-9C87-00AA005127ED%7D%22%3D%22WebCheckWebCrawler%22%2C%20you%20may%20change%20the%20%7B1%7D%20to%20%7B2%7D%20%22to%20highlight%20this%22%20or%20to%20%7B3%7D%20to%20%22highlight%20me%22.). **Note** that `.*?` is replaced with `[^"]*` to make sure no `"` could be matched in between `"..."` or the `(?<=^(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")` lookbehind would match many more strings here.

Powershell code snippet:

```
Select-String '(?<=^(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"){1}[^"]*")[^"]*(?=")' -input $str | % { $_.matches.value }
```

In PCRE, you could use

```php
^(?:.*?"[^"]*"){1}.*?"\K[^"]*(?=")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2KjJh/2/). The `\K` omits the whole text matched so far from the overall memory match, so all that is returned is the portion of text matched with the last `[^"]*` (`(?=")` is a positive lookahead whose pattern match is not added to the overall match as this is a non-consuming pattern). It is good to use in PHP, R, Sublime Text (PCRE), Ruby (Onigmo), Notepad++ (Boost). Powershell does not support `\K`, unfortunately.

**Current scenario solution**

You do not need to use such a complex patterns. You may use

```
="([^"]+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/6).

*Details*

- `="` - a `="` substring
- `([^"]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"`.

Grab the value inside Group 1, `$matches[1]`.

In Powershell, the value you need can be obtained like this:

```
PS> $str = '"{08165EA0-E946-11CF-9C87-00AA005127ED}"="WebCheckWebCrawler"';
PS> $pattern = '="([^"]+)"'
PS> $str -match $pattern
True
PS> $matches[1]
WebCheckWebCrawler
PS>
```

Comment: I found this question because I'm also trying to "match second occurrence of character set in in quotes", which was the premise of colonel_claypoo's question.  This answer solves colonel_claypoo's problem by leveraging the = character, which does not exist in the string I'm regex'ing.  The accepted answer would be more useful to the community if it presented a solution to the question as stated instead of exploiting a unique characteristic of colonel_claypoo's circumstance to solve his problem.

Comment: @BrytonBeesley Expanded it a bit. I still think in each case the solution can be different depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew for the excellent elaboration!  I have upvoted your answer because its detail and scope will undoubtedly help the community, and I learned a great deal from it.  I'm using the Sublime text editor and the python library `re`, which unfortunately is the only of five flavors modeled in the regex101.com demo that fails.  Thanks to the explained caveats that you have provided, I now know the limitations of the tools I am using.  Thank you for taking your valuable time to make this answer even better!

Comment: @BrytonBeesley SublimeText3 uses PCRE regex library in its search and replace feature. If you are working on some custom syntax highlighting, those rules use Oniguruma engine, which is again similar to PCRE, but there are other problems with input rather than with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let str = '"{08165EA0-E946-11CF-9C87-00AA005127ED}"="WebCheckWebCrawler"';
console.log(str.match(/(?<=\=)".*?"/g));
```

Comment: Thanks. This selects the first quotes as well. Ideally I'd only like the string inside the quotes. Would you mind tweaking it?

Answer (score -1):

To capture you can use:

`="(.*)"`

Check [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/8)

You can also use: `="(.*?)"`

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it so that only the strings in between the quotes are selected.