# Powershell/Regex to parse Nth occurrence, tab delimited string from multiple lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm new to regex and completely at a loss on how to go about this, so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction. I need to capture a specific field from tab delimited text from the clipboard of multiple lines with powershell. I had been copying this data to a text editor and saving as a csv. So my goal here is to eliminate those interim steps. In my example text below I need to capture the field after the first tab. In others I need to capture the 3rd or 5th field while other sets of data don't have a leading and trailing tabs for each line but, all fields are separated by tabs. The "->" represent tabs in my example.

```
->BCCH60M2X2->16830009->bcc\sajghjhy->->Active->->->11/15/2021 8:09:00 PM->11/15/2021 6:21:00 PM->->
->BCCHDNN2X2->->bcc\bdfgfgos->bcc\bdgcs->Active->->->11/11/2021 2:44:00 PM->11/16/2021 9:44:00 AM->->
->BCCJ9YGXD3->16831532->bcc\elfdfdi->->Active->->->11/11/2021 5:14:00 PM->11/11/2021 9:43:00 AM->->
->N3-310-Dsdf2X2->->->->Active->->->11/11/2021 4:30:00 PM->11/11/2021 2:37:00 PM->->
->BCC013843284653->16833803->bcc\bccsupport->->Active->->->10/14/2021 10:53:00 AM->10/14/2021 10:43:00 AM->->
```

This post is similar to what I'm after - [RegEx: Match second occurrence of character set in in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095643/regex-match-second-occurrence-of-character-set-in-in-quotes/51100880#51100880). Unfortunately I haven't had any success in modifying the examples there to search for strings between tab characters instead of between quotes.

Thanks for any input you can offer.

Comment: Are the `->` tokens in your post supposed to signify a tab?

Comment: If these are TAB delimited files, why not treat them as they are? **TAB delimited CSV files** without headers. There's a cmdlet for that called [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)

Comment: Can you please write your expected output?

Comment: Yes, the tokens signify tabs.

Comment: Ideally I'd end up with a powershell object that contains only a single field from the original file.

Comment: Theo - I'm afraid that I misled you with my question. The data that I need to parse is from the clipboard. I'll update my question with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

As Theo commented, if it's tab delimited, just use `Import-Csv`. You can provide headers, then just select those properties you're after.

I doubt your data actually looks like what you've posted, but that's what we've got to work with for the time being. Here's an example.

```
@'
->BCCH60M2X2->16830009->bcc\sajghjhy->->Active->->->11/15/2021 8:09:00 PM->11/15/2021 6:21:00 PM->->
->BCCHDNN2X2->->bcc\bdfgfgos->bcc\bdgcs->Active->->->11/11/2021 2:44:00 PM->11/16/2021 9:44:00 AM->->
->BCCJ9YGXD3->16831532->bcc\elfdfdi->->Active->->->11/11/2021 5:14:00 PM->11/11/2021 9:43:00 AM->->
->N3-310-Dsdf2X2->->->->Active->->->11/11/2021 4:30:00 PM->11/11/2021 2:37:00 PM->->
->BCC013843284653->16833803->bcc\bccsupport->->Active->->->10/14/2021 10:53:00 AM->10/14/2021 10:43:00 AM->->
'@ -replace '->',"`t" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter `t -Header @(1..10)
```

You'll see nice objects with properties 1 through 10. Select the ones you want.

```
$csvdata = @'
->BCCH60M2X2->16830009->bcc\sajghjhy->->Active->->->11/15/2021 8:09:00 PM->11/15/2021 6:21:00 PM->->
->BCCHDNN2X2->->bcc\bdfgfgos->bcc\bdgcs->Active->->->11/11/2021 2:44:00 PM->11/16/2021 9:44:00 AM->->
->BCCJ9YGXD3->16831532->bcc\elfdfdi->->Active->->->11/11/2021 5:14:00 PM->11/11/2021 9:43:00 AM->->
->N3-310-Dsdf2X2->->->->Active->->->11/11/2021 4:30:00 PM->11/11/2021 2:37:00 PM->->
->BCC013843284653->16833803->bcc\bccsupport->->Active->->->10/14/2021 10:53:00 AM->10/14/2021 10:43:00 AM->->
'@ -replace '->',"`t" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter `t -Header @(1..10)

$csvdata | Select-Object -Property '3', '4', '9'

3        4              9                     
-        -              -                     
16830009 bcc\sajghjhy   11/15/2021 8:09:00 PM 
         bcc\bdfgfgos   11/11/2021 2:44:00 PM 
16831532 bcc\elfdfdi    11/11/2021 5:14:00 PM 
                        11/11/2021 4:30:00 PM 
16833803 bcc\bccsupport 10/14/2021 10:53:00 AM
```

Of course when reading from a file it will look more like this.

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv -Path \path\to\file.csv -Delimiter `t -Header @(1..10)
```

You can give it meaningful header names instead.

**Edit**

My answer still applies to the text, whether it's in your clipboard, a file, etc. So for your example, the field after the first tab..

```
@'
->BCCH60M2X2->16830009->bcc\sajghjhy->->Active->->->11/15/2021 8:09:00 PM->11/15/2021 6:21:00 PM->->
->BCCHDNN2X2->->bcc\bdfgfgos->bcc\bdgcs->Active->->->11/11/2021 2:44:00 PM->11/16/2021 9:44:00 AM->->
->BCCJ9YGXD3->16831532->bcc\elfdfdi->->Active->->->11/11/2021 5:14:00 PM->11/11/2021 9:43:00 AM->->
->N3-310-Dsdf2X2->->->->Active->->->11/11/2021 4:30:00 PM->11/11/2021 2:37:00 PM->->
->BCC013843284653->16833803->bcc\bccsupport->->Active->->->10/14/2021 10:53:00 AM->10/14/2021 10:43:00 AM->->
'@ -replace '->',"`t" | Set-Clipboard

$csvdata = Get-Clipboard | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter `t -Header @(1..10)

$csvdata | Select-Object -Property '2'
```

Outputs

```
2              
-              
BCCH60M2X2     
BCCHDNN2X2     
BCCJ9YGXD3     
N3-310-Dsdf2X2 
BCC013843284653
```

If you just want the values, add `-ExpandProperty` to the `Select-Object` command.

```
$csvdata | Select-Object -ExpandProperty '2'
```

Comment: Doug, Thank you for the thorough answer. I need to back up a little though since my original question was misleading. I've edited my question now with more detail to help clarify. I'm familiar with import-csv, it wasn't clear to me how to use it without first saving the data to a file. Which is what led me to possibly using regex.

Comment: Thanks again. That answers my question.

Comment: Get-ClipBoard? Glad to have helped. You may consider marking it as the solution by clicking the checkmark. You can change this later if a better answer comes along